# Leaflet multiple slider

Tags: leaflet, slider, geojson

i am using this plugin https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider, i am trying create 2 slider control and combine them but don't know how can i do. Thank you for reading my question and sorry because my english is bad.

Here my code slider control:

```
$.getJSON("{% url 'hostel' %}", function (json) {

            hostel_datasets.addData(json);

            //For a Range-Slider use the range property:
            sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
                    position: "topright",
                    layer: hostel_datasets, 
                    timeAttribute: "price",
                    //isEpoch: true,
                    showAllOnStart: true,
                    range: true
            });

            slider_date = L.control.sliderControl({
                    position: "topright",
                    layer: hostel_datasets, 
                    timeAttribute: "updated_at",
                    //isEpoch: true,
                    showAllOnStart: true,
                    range: true
            });

            //Make sure to add the slider to the map ;-)
            map.addControl(sliderControl);
            map.addControl(slider_date);

            sliderControl.options.markers.sort(function(a, b) {
                return (a.feature.properties.price > b.feature.properties.price);
            });

            //And initialize the slider
            sliderControl.startSlider();
            slider_date.startSlider();

            var htmlObject = sliderControl.getContainer();
            var a = document.getElementById('form4');
            function setParent(el, newParent)
            {
                newParent.appendChild(el);
            }
            setParent(htmlObject, a);
        });
```

My result:
[My img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlSVj.png)

Only show one slider control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin is not good coded ...

When you look in the code, you see that it creates a div with a `id` and selecting the container by id. So when you add a second slider, it becomes also the same id, but when you call `.startSlider()` on the second slider, it selects by id and get only the first slider.

https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/a797b08d692b9c9deaf5602ebeb99923d8764f5e/SliderControl.js#L106

I recommand you to overwrite the plugin.

Comment: i am very new to javascript, do you know other plugins similar to this one ?

Comment: I created a new version: https://github.com/Falke-Design/LeafletSlider

Comment: Thank you so much for improving this plugin but when i try to run your example, i only see one slider control is work and another slider control isn't work

Comment: look at: https://falke-design.github.io/LeafletSlider/examples/epoch.html

Comment: wow it worked, now i am trying sync two slider example: search price from 1200 to 1500 on date 17/4/2020, do you have solution about it ?